# Subclipse recognizes changes after changing the ignore file?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I use Subclipse in Eclipse. After adding some files to the SVN ignore list of the root directory and all subdirectories, the Synchronize View shows changes for all directories. No file inside a directory has changed, it only shows the directories have changed (black outgoing arrow on each directory).

I am confused, because how can a directory change which already existed?

Trying to compare the directory with the latest version of the repository says "There are no differences with the selected inputs".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `svn:ignore` property has been set in each folder.  Since svn properties are also versioned, this constitutes a change with respect to the repository.  This would be true for any client and not just Subclipse.  I'm not familiar with Subclipse so I don't know why this isn't appearing in a diff, but I know TortoiseSVN which does.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you! How are folder properties (like ignore files) kept by SVN? In a separate ignore file?

Comment: I assume that the properties are kept somewhere in the `_svn` folder of your working copy.

Answer (score 1):

You changed the properties of the directories to ignore those filenames. There aren't any *content* differences - just directory properties.